# Svg polygon Stroke

Tags: html, svg, polygon

I'm new to Svg and can't figure out why I'm unable to add a stroke to this polygon

```
    <img class="clip-svg" src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/1000" />

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                <polygon points="0,1 0.15,0 1,0 0.85,1" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:5"/>
        </clipPath>
    </svg>
```

My CSS:

```
    .clip-svg{
      -webkit-clip-path: url(#myClip);
       clip-path: url(#myClip);
       max-height:150rem;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

A clipPath just defines the shape to be cut away. You can't style a clip path.